# Update android SDK : install latest platform to implement new APIs such as "ShortcutManager"

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-shortcutmanager

Here i am performing demo for Android Shortcuts introduces in android nougat [App Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/preview/shortcuts.html)

I have used following code to create app shortcut

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
    ShortcutInfo shortcut;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
        shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, "second_shortcut")
                .setShortLabel(getString(R.string.str_shortcut_two))
                .setLongLabel(getString(R.string.str_shortcut_two_desc))
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in")))
                .build();
        shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut));
    }
}
```

But here i am getting **compile time error** `cannot resolve symbol ShortcutManager`.

Here is my `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

Comment: App Shortcuts were introduced in API 25+. They are not part of the support library yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your `dependency` because `ShortcutManager` is added in API 25 as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.html) so you should update/install the below components for API 25

- Build-Tools
- Install API 25 platform
- Android Support Respository
- SDK Tools
- SDK Platform Tools

and make the necessary changes in your `build-gradle file` as show in the image too :

Update your following project’s values to 25

- compileSdkVersion
- buildToolsVersion

Follow the [link to see](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html) the features updates provided in API 25 (v7.1)

And eventually it will look this, with succesful build using `ShortcutManager`

[image]

There are some other crucial packages you might want to update too

- USB drivers   : For USB device debugging
- Play service  : For latest APIs added in Google maps,google+ etc
- System images : To practice with latest AVD devices
- Android Support Repository : Support libraries for android devices,TV etc
- Google Repository : For features Firebase, Google Maps, Games achievements and leaderboards

Comment: Ok, in that case i will update my sdk and let you know whether its working or not.