# Android Studio not recognizing ShortcutManager class

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

I'm looking into shortcut creation with Android O.  Unfortunately Android Studio is not recognizing the ShortcutManager class:

[image]

In the gradle file I have set as a dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

In the gradle file I have these versions set:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
```

I have followed the steps in this [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30698604/2595659) and executed **File => Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

Unfortunately Android Studio continues to not recognize the class.

Information on my version of Android Studio:

```
Android Studio 2.3.2
Build #AI-162.3934792, built on April 21, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Attempting to manually import the class is not successful:

[image]

Comment: What is your `compileSdkVersion`? `ShortcutManager` was added in API Level 25 IIRC.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry for the omission, I've updated the post.

Comment: What version of Android Studio is this? If you add `import android.content.pm.ShortcutManager;` yourself, what happens?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the followup; I've added to the post addressing your questions.

Comment: Try to clean (`Build -> Clean Project`) and rebuild (`Build -> Rebuild Project`)

Comment: @Alexey it results in `error: cannot find symbol class ShortcutManager`

Comment: Can you please provide full source code of the class, including import section?

Comment: Something is seriously messed up in your environment. Short of reinstalling the Android SDK, I do not know what to suggest to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459174/update-android-sdk-install-latest-platform-to-implement-new-apis-such-as-shor

Answer (score 0):

In addition to assuring that Android Studio version number is at 2.3, the breakthrough I had was finding this documentation for [migrating to Android O](https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html).  In the section "Get the Android O SDK" it prescribes both platform and tool updates that are initiated by launching from the Android Studio menu **Tools > Android > SDK Manager**.

Here's a screenshot for which platform components I needed to update:

[image]

When combined with the required tools updates, these were combined updates required:

[image]

Then, you must take care to follow the required updates to your build configuration outlined in the section "Update your build configuration", an element that I had missed was the maven update:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.0-rc3'

  defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 26
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
}

// REQUIRED: Google's new Maven repo is required for the latest
// support library that is compatible with Android O
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```